# Flower doesn't display all workers for celery

Tags: python, celery, flower

I am running celery on two servers with one redis as a broker.

Celery start command looks like following:

```
celery multi start 2 -A app_name
```

Flower start command:

```
celery flower -A app_name --address=10.41.31.210 --port=5555
```

In flower's output there are some warnings:

```
WARNING:flower.api.control:'stats' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'active_queues' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'registered' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'scheduled' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'active' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'reserved' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'revoked' inspect method failed
WARNING:flower.api.control:'conf' inspect method failed
```

And the most strange thing for me - not all workers are displayed in Flower's dashboard. Seems that after every flower restart only some workers are displayed. Due to my start scripts - there should be at least 8 workers, but I see 4 or sometimes 6.

Looking for any solution or advice. Thank you.

P.s I don't have any problems with the same services when there is only one server used for celery workers.

Comment: did you found solution?

Comment: @PankajJackson checkout my answer

Answer (score 10):

Problem here that, flower starts before celery is ready

This could be easily checked with `celery inspect ping`

Here is example from my project `start_flower.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

until timeout -t 10 celery -A project inspect ping; do
    >&2 echo "Celery workers not available"
done

echo 'Starting flower'
celery -A project flower
```

Comment: `timeout -t 10` didn't seem to work as expected so I replace it with `timeout 10s` and that seemed to work better.

Comment: @Chad what operating system you are using?

Comment: I'm using docker image `python:3.6-slim` which I believe is from debian

Comment: I got `timeout: invalid option -- 't'` on docker image `python:3.8`. `until timeout 10s celery -A project inspect ping; do` works better

Answer (score 2):

Try it :

```
shell > celery -A app_name worker -l info

another shell > celery -A djangocelery flower
```

it works....